# Nightmarejs multiple pages in same test

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to pull the title-tag text from two webpages on a Drupal site.  I want to use Nightmarejs.

Here is my code so far:

```
// get the <title> text from inside the Drupal site
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var user = 'foobar@example.com';
var pass = 'foobar';

new Nightmare()
  .goto('http://example.com/user')
    .type('#edit-name', user)
    .type('#edit-pass', pass)
    .click('.searchsubmit')
    .wait()
    .evaluate(function () {
       return document.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0];
       }, function (res) {
      console.log('Homepage title: '+res.text);
    })
    .run(function(err, nightmare){
      console.log('Done1.');

      // step 2
      nightmare
        .goto('http://example.com/admin')
        .wait()
        .evaluate(function () {
          return document.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0];
          }, function (res) {
         console.log('Admin page title: '+res.text);
        })   
        .run(function(err, nightmare){
          console.log('Done2.');
        })
      ;
    })
 ;
```

When I run this, with: *node app.js* I am able to log in successfully to the first page.  Unfortunately when I try to open the second page I see an access refused on the second page call (http://example.com/admin).  The session is not being carried into the second "goto" command.

What can I do to be able to open up many pages with the same nightmarejs session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I discovered that it seems goto() should be used only once.  In order to switch to a new page, I use click() instead of an additional goto().

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried chaining the goto methods?

```
 new Nightmare()
  .goto('http://example.com/user')
    .type('#edit-name', user)
    .type('#edit-pass', pass)
    .click('.searchsubmit')
    .wait()
    .evaluate(function () {
       return document.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0];
       }, function (res) {
      console.log('Homepage title: '+res.text);
    })
    .goto('http://example.com/admin')
        .wait()
        .evaluate(function () {
          return document.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0];
          }, function (res) {
         console.log('Admin page title: '+res.text);
        })   
        .run(function(err, nightmare){
          console.log('Done2.');
        })
      ;
    }).run();
```

From reading the [api docs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api) run only executes the commands that came before it.